# Import nestjs module directly from another module without Importing to AppModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am new to nestJs, and I am creating a module called `example .module` and importing another module called `DB.Module`, but I am getting the following error if I am not importing `DB.Module` in `App.Module`. is it compulsory to import all of module in `App.Module`

```
[Nest] 45706  - 07/19/2023, 7:47:55 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 45706  - 07/19/2023, 7:47:55 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the DbexampleService (?, MysqlService). Please make sure that the argument MongoService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
- If MongoService is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If MongoService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing MongoService */ ]
  })
```

**File: `example.module.ts`**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DbexampleService } from './services/dbexample/dbexample.service';
import { HttpExampleService } from './services/http-example/http-example.service';
import { MongoService } from 'src/global/dbModule/services/mongo.service';
import { MysqlService } from 'src/global/dbModule/services/mysql.service';
import { DBModule } from '../global/dbModule/db.module';

@Module({
    imports: [ DBModule],
    providers:[DbexampleService, HttpExampleService, MongoService, MysqlService]
})
export class ExamplesModule {}
```

**File: `DB.module.ts`**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongoService } from './services/mongo.service';
import { DBController } from './controllers/db.controller';
import { MysqlService } from './services/mysql.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [DBController],
  providers: [MongoService, MysqlService],
  exports:[MongoService, MysqlService]
})
export class DBModule {}
```

**File: `App.module.ts`**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { configuration } from '../config/configuration';
import { DbexampleService } from './examples/services/dbexample/dbexample.service';
import { DbexampleController } from './examples/controllers/dbexample/dbexample.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration]
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, DbexampleController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    DbexampleService
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Question: Is it compulsory to import all of module in `App.module` ?, if no then how can resolve this error ?

Comment: the error is because your `AppModule` doesn't know the provider that `DbexampleService` provider depends on. Also, `AppModule` is usually intended to be the root module, the entry point. To fix that you need to import `ExamplesModule` into `AppModule`, and add `DbexampleService` to the `exports` array of `ExamplesModule`

Comment: @MicaelLevi will you check this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76728781/axios-instance-token-at-index-0-is-available-in-the-appmodule-context, I am facing some issue there

Comment: Hi @MicaelLevi I am facing another issue will you help in that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76997482/nest-js-library-module-dependency-resolution-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting `DBModule` in `example.module.ts` and import `ExamplesModule` in `AppModule`.

Comment: Thanks @Mohd its working but it will great if you can explain the logic as well

Comment: What actually happening here is you are trying to use ```DBModule``` in your App without letting the App module know of  its dependencies. The solution I suggested is based on docs topic https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting you can learn more from here.

Comment: will you check this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722409/import-nestjs-module-directly-from-another-module-without-importing-to-appmodule, I am getting facing some issue

Comment: @AvinashA Is my solution not working?

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly  fine, I was facing some other issue so tagged you here

Comment: can you mention what issues are you facing?

Comment: It’s resolved now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76728781/axios-instance-token-at-index-0-is-available-in-the-appmodule-context

Comment: Hi @Mohd I am facing another issue will you help in that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76997482/nest-js-library-module-dependency-resolution-issue