# AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AppModule context

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am using Axios in nestJs project and but I am getting the following error while using `HttpService` in `Item-module`

```
[Nest] 74973  - 07/20/2023, 3:28:01 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
```

I am sharing my code kindly suggestion what is the issue in this code
**File-Path: `src/app.module.ts`**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration]
    }),
    CamiModule,
    ExamplesModule,
    ItemModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR, useClass: PerformanceMonitor
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**File-Path: `src/item/item.module.ts`**

```
@Module({
    imports: [HttpModule],
    providers: [ItemService],
    exports: [ItemService],
})
export class ItemModule { }
```

**File-Path: `src/item/item.service.ts`**

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
    AxiosRequestConfig,
    AxiosResponse,
} from 'axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) { }

    // Get methood
    async get<T>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
        try {
            const response = await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.get<T>(url, config));
            return response;
        } catch(error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `HttpService` provider from `@nestjs/axios` will be registered by `HttpModule`. So you must not add it to your `providers` array. Just remove that and it should work. Follow the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-modulez