# Nest.js Library Module Dependency Resolution Issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've encountered a dependency resolution issue while using a Nest.js library module called **`HttpHandlerModule`** in a different project called `Test-Nest-Npm-Library`. I've created the **`HttpHandlerModule`** library to handle HTTP requests using the Nest Axios library. The module is supposed to be configurable using options such as timeout. However, when I try to use this module in another project and configure it using a configuration file, I'm encountering the following error:

```
[Nest] ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument [object Object] at index [0] is available in the HttpModule context.
```

I've gone through the documentation and relevant resources, but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of this issue. Here is some code that might help provide context:

**Library Module Code (HttpHandlerModule):**

```
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [HttpHandlerService],
  exports: [HttpHandlerService]
})
export class HttpHandlerModule {
  static registerAsync(options: HttpModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: HttpHandlerModule,
      imports: [
        HttpModule.registerAsync({
          useFactory: async (httpModuleOptions) => {
            return {
              timeout: httpModuleOptions.get('http.timeout')
            }
          },
          inject: [this.createAsyncProviders(options)]
        }),
      ],
      providers: this.createAsyncProviders(options)
    };
  }

  private static createAsyncProviders(
    options: HttpModuleAsyncOptions
  ): Provider[] {
    if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
      return [this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options)];
    }
    return [
      this.createAsyncOptionsProvider(options),
      {
        provide: options.useClass,
        useClass: options.useClass
      }
    ];
  }

  private static createAsyncOptionsProvider(
    options: HttpModuleAsyncOptions
  ): Provider {
    if (options.useFactory) {
      return {
        provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: options.useFactory,
        inject: options.inject || [],
      };
    } else if (options.useExisting) {
      return {
        provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS,
        useExisting: options.useExisting,
      };
    }
    return undefined;
  }

}
```

**Code to Use the Library Module in Another Project:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
      cache: true
    }),
    HttpHandlerModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        timeout: configService.get('http.timeout'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The HttpHandlerModule module is meant to be flexible and configurable, but I seem to be missing something crucial here. Any insights into this issue or suggestions on how to troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update:**

Upon further investigation, I noticed that the issue might be related to how I'm trying to inject the configuration value into the HttpHandlerModule. I've posted the relevant code above. Is there a specific step I'm missing or a best practice that I should follow for injecting configuration values into a Nest.js library module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `inject` section in below code:

```
private static createHttpProvider(options: HttpOptions): any[] {
  return [{ provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS, useValue: options || {}, inject: [HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS] }];
}
```

to:

```
private static createHttpProvider(options: HttpOptions): any[] {
  return [{ provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS, useValue: options || {} }];
}
```

When you have the `inject`, Nest will try to create the `HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS` itself and then fail because you are not providing the dependencies required by its constructor.

Comment: I am not using `createHttpProvider` in my code, I am using `createAsyncProviders` and this one is throwing error

Comment: @AvinashA  You are using `createHttpProvider` in your library code.

Comment: I have updated my code but still the error i am getting from
```
private static createAsyncOptionsProvider(
    options: HttpModuleAsyncOptions
  ): Provider {
    if (options.useFactory) {
      return {
        provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: options.useFactory,
        inject: options.inject,
      };
    } else if (options.useExisting) {
      return {
        provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS,
        useExisting: options.useExisting,
      };
    }
    return undefined;
  }
``` 
from this section i.e option.inject
```

Comment: I have also console my option 
```
{
  useFactory: [AsyncFunction: useFactory],
  inject: [ [class ConfigService] ]
}
```
I think config module is not included

Comment: @AvinashA Do you have a public github I can take a look at? Will be easier for me to debug.

Comment: Not right now but i will create and let you know

Comment: @AvinashA Any update on this?

Comment: I will create in this week and let you know